# Variadic template taking reference to data types

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I would like to create a wrapper for class methods so I used a variable template and std::tuple to wrap the method. It works as I need, but I cannot figure out how to be able to wrap a method with parameters called by reference. Please see the main function below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;

namespace helper {

template <std::size_t... Ts> struct index {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Ts> struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N - 1, N - 1, Ts...> {};

template <std::size_t... Ts> struct gen_seq<0, Ts...> : index<Ts...> {};

template<class F, class... Ts, std::size_t... Is> void for_each_in_tuple(std::tuple<Ts...> &tuple, F func, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander {
        0, ((void)func(std::get<Is>(tuple)), 0)...
    };
}

template<class F, class...Ts> void for_each_in_tuple(std::tuple<Ts...> &tuple, F func)
{
    for_each_in_tuple(tuple, func, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}
}

enum class Result : std::int32_t {
    Result1 = 1,
    Result2 = 2
};

template<typename... Args> class Procedure {
private:

    std::function<Result(Args...)> m_method;
    std::tuple<Args...> args;

    template <typename... Args, std::size_t... Is> Result callMethod(std::tuple<Args...> &tup, helper::index<Is...>)
    {
        return  m_method(std::get<Is>(tup)...);
    }

    template <typename... Args> Result callMethod(std::tuple<Args...> &tup)
    {
        return callMethod(tup, helper::gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)> {});
    }

public:

    template <typename ...Args> void setMethod(const std::function<Result(Args &&... args)> &method)
    {
        m_method = method;
    }
};

class MethodsClass {

public:

    Result doSomething(std::int32_t input, double output)
    {
        return Result::Result1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    **// This works fine**
    MethodsClass methods;
    Procedure <std::int32_t, double> procedure1;
    procedure1.setMethod<std::int32_t, double>(std::bind(&MethodsClass::doSomething1, methods, _1, _2));

    **// This end with compiler error std::tuple<int32_t,double &>::tuple': no appropriate default constructor available**

    Procedure <std::int32_t, double &> procedure2;
    procedure2.setMethod<std::int32_t, double &>(std::bind(&MethodsClass::doSomething2, methods, _1, _2));

    return 0;
}
```

I know why the second case does not compile, the message is clear and it is obvious that a reference has to be initialized. But how to do it in this case? How to initialize std:tuple, how and where to expand the arguments pack? I am missing something and can't realize what.

Comment: You might want to look into how the standard library uses [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) (that's the object created by `std::ref` and `std::cref`).

Comment: The problematic `std::tuple<Args...> args;` is unused...

Comment: `std::function<Result(Args &&... args)>` should be `std::function<Result(Args... args)>` or even `F&& f`.

Comment: You hide your class `Args...` in your method, better to use different names...

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to pay enough attention to rvalue/lvalue context of call.  If I set up a procedure, the legality and efficiency of calling it will change depending on if I call it and discard the arguments (ie, move from the arguments) or call it and expect the arguments to persist (maybe so I can call it more than once).  Second, have you considered `std::function<void()>`?

Comment: I simplified the code a bit, in reality `std::tuple<Args...> args;` is used. I will consider `std::function<void()>` once it works with arguments. I already tried `std::reference_wrapper` but still can't get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in C++17 it is quite easy. The tuple has to be declared:

```
std::tuple<typename std::decay<Args>::type...> m_args;
```

Then all the recursive tuple unpacking can be simply removed and replaced by:

```
std::apply(m_method, m_args);
```